# I want to add Item button on top in multi field component

Tags: aem

I want to create custom multi field in aem and add "add Item" label at the beginning",the will currently appearing at the bottom can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add everything you've tried, as we all any other details about problems you are facing. There are many examples on line of AEM dialog customization, please start there and let us know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2394012
You can creat fields and label in a single line, in your AEM dialog by adding custom CSS.

Comment: require in classic UI